# Why does a C# ListView control with View set to Details remain empty?

Tags: c#, listview

I'm trying to figure out how to use a ListView control with View set to Details.

It's no problem if View is set to LargeIcon, SmallIcon, List or Tile, but when I set View to Details the ListView control remains empty no matter what I do.

I have tried perhaps 100 different examples, all with the same result.

What may be the root to this problem? And how can it be solved?

---

Update: I'm now using an HTML table, styled with CSS and displayed in a WebBrowser control. I think it's a rather good solution; if it's the final solution remains to be seen.

Comment: Could you post your XAML?  It may be as simple as no columns being defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to answer your question without seeing any code, but I suggest closely examining the code in [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.view%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) on MSDN which uses ListView Details.

My guess is that you're not adding SubItems to your ListViewItem objects.

Comment: The MSDN page was new to me. It seems promising! Thanks! I will check it out later, because shortly after I posted this question I decided to try and use a DataGridView control instead.

Answer (score 9):

To use `View.Details`, you also have to supply a list of column header by filling out the `Columns` property of your `ListView`. Your items will then be displayed under the first header, and the subitems will be displayed under subsequent headers.

Answer (score 8):

I was struggling with this one. I found that in the code, I was using to add the items, I cleared down the list first, then added the items. My error was that I used `myList.Clear()` and not `MyList.Items.Clear()`, which, I can only assume, was clearing everything.

Answer (score 4):

Select the ListView in the designer.  Click the triangle at the upper right edge, Edit Columns, Add.  Repeat as necessary for as many columns you want in the view.  You can drag the column splitters in the designer to get them to the right width.